# Returning AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, json, encoding, elasticsearch

I'm having some issues with this, I keep getting:

`AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'`

When I run it.

I thought UTF-8 would be the go to for this. Subscribers will only ever return numbers, or NoneTypes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import urllib2,time,csv,json,requests,urlparse,pdb



SEARCH_URL = urllib2.unquote("http://soyuz.elastic.tubularlabs.net:9200/intelligence_v2/channel_intelligence/%s")

reader = csv.reader(open('input.csv', 'r+U'), delimiter=',', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
#cookie = {"user": "2|1:0|10:1438908462|4:user|36:eyJhaWQiOiA1Njk3LCAiaWQiOiA2MzQ0fQ==|b5c4b3adbd96e54833bf8656625aedaf715d4905f39373b860c4b4bc98655e9e"}

myfile = open('accounts.csv','w')

writer = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

processCount = 1
idsToProcess = []
for row in reader:
    if len(row)>0:
        idsToProcess.append(row[0])
#idsToProcess = ['fba_491452930867938']
for userID in idsToProcess:
#   print "fetching for %s.." % fbid
    url = SEARCH_URL % userID
    facebooksubscribers = None
    Instagramsubscribers = None
    vinesubscribers = None

    response = requests.request("GET", url)
    ret = response.json()
    titleResponse = ret['_source']['title']

    try:
        facebooksubscribers = ret['_source']['facebook']['subscribers']          
    except:
        facebooksubscribers = " "

    try:
        instagramsubscribers = ret['_source']['instagram']['subscribers']
    except:
        instagramsubscribers = " "

    try:
        vinesubscribers = ret['_source']['vine']['subscribers']
    except:
        vinesubscribers = " "



    time.sleep(0)

    row = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in [userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers]]
    writer.writerow(row)

    #writer.writerow([userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers,twitterURL])

    myfile.flush()

    print u"%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s" % (processCount,userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers)
    processCount += 1
    #print sumEngs

    #print vidToEngs
    #print sum(vidToEngs.values())
myfile.close()
exit()
```

Comment: because one of these `[userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers]` element is int and you can't perform encode operation on int. You may want to do the type casting in your for loop. Replace `row = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in [userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers]]` with `row = [str(s).encode('utf-8') for s in [userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers]]`

Comment: @Pramod you should post an answer with your solution, which looks perfectly valid to me, too.

Comment: @Pramod Thanks for the tip. I'm now getting another error here:  `SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xe2' in file SubscribersPullCrossPlatform.py on line 49, but no encoding declared; `

Comment: @Waveformer put `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` at the top of your file then.

Comment: @Pramod Thanks for helping out here. After adding to the header, I now get `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)`

Answer (score 11):

Use this :

```
repr(s).encode('utf-8')
```

instead of :

```
s.encode('utf-8')
```

Answer (score 7):

because one of these

```
[userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers]‌
```

element is int and you can't perform encode operation on int. You may want to do the type casting in your for loop. Replace

```
row = [s.encode('utf-8') for s in [userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers]]‌​
```

with

```
row = [str(s).encode('utf-8') for s in [userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers]]‌
```

​

Comment: There still seems to be some issues. I'm finding encoding to be a sensitive area when running scripts like this one.

Comment: @Waveformer Now this is different issue, to debug this problem I have to simulate your problem in my side. You have to look into type of character in your string where you are performing encoding operation. But make sure while doing converstion you don't get any noise.

Comment: interestingly enough it managed to do one before throwing the error:

`1,Y30JRSgfhYXA6i6xX1erWg,Smosh,6947355,1806850,412974
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SubscribersPullCrossPlatform.py", line 51, in <module>
    row = [str(s).encode('utf-8') for s in [userID,titleResponse,facebooksubscribers,instagramsubscribers,vinesubscribers]]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
(venv)Maxs-MacBook-Pro:Leaderboard Scripts maxramsay$ `

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7 copy the code for UTF8Recoder and UnicodeWriter from https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/csv.html. It uses `unicode(s, "utf-8")`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when loading data from an xlsx file. The problem I ran into after implementing the solutions above was that I would receive the error:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

since the data I was parsing was not just unicode. The solution I found was a simple try/except where I only .encode('utf-8') if an error gets thrown. Here is the code:

```
    try:
        s2 = str(foo)
    except:
        s2 = foo.encode('utf-8').strip()
```

I don't know if this was a one off thing or if other people might be having this issue. I hope this helps.